# using Promise to ensure a filestream has ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I start off with the following two variables

```
var yearTotal2008 = 0; 
var year2008TallyByPatient = {};
```

Then read through each line of a big csv file, updating the two variables accordingly. This takes a while.

```
const produceChartData = () => {
  inputStream
    .pipe(CsvReadableStream())
    .on('data', function (row) {
      if ((20080101 <= row[3]) && (row[3] <= 20081231)) {
        yearTotal2008 += parseFloat(row[6])
        yearPatientTally(year2008TallyByPatient, row[0], parseFloat(row[6]))
      }
})
    .on('end', function (data) {
      console.log('end of the read')
      console.log('year total claims: ' + yearTotal2008)
      console.log('average claims by patient: ' + averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient))
      return;
    })
  }
```

I want to make sure that the stream has finished and all the relevant values have been added to the two variables.

```
function resolveGetCall (getCall) {
  return Promise.resolve(getCall)
}

resolveGetCall(produceChartData())
  .then(result => { 
    return Promise.resolve(averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient)) 
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

output comes out something like this

```
NaN
end of the read
year total claims: 125329820
average claims by patient: 2447.70
```

I've been looking through other threads on here and it's just not clicking for me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `produceChartData` is not returning anything at the moment. You need to convert it to return a `Promise` that resolves `on('end'`. (Just using `Promise.resolve(getCall)` won't make anything asynchronous automatically wait)

For example:

```
const produceChartData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    inputStream
      .pipe(CsvReadableStream())
      .on('data', function (row) {
        if ((20080101 <= row[3]) && (row[3] <= 20081231)) {
          yearTotal2008 += parseFloat(row[6])
          yearPatientTally(year2008TallyByPatient, row[0], parseFloat(row[6]))
        }
      })
      .on('end', function (data) {
        console.log('end of the read')
        console.log('year total claims: ' + yearTotal2008)
        console.log('average claims by patient: ' + averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient))
        resolve();
      })
  });
}
```

Then you can call `then` durectly on a call of `produceChartData`:

```
produceChartData()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all done');
  });
```

I see you're using

```
return Promise.resolve(averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient))
```

If `averageClaimByPatient` operates asynchronously, then you'll need to convert it to return a `Promise` as well, just like `produceChartData` was modified above. Then, just `return` the `Promise`:

```
.then(() => {
  return averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wrap `averageClaimByPatient` into a promise resolve, how can I make something like this work `produceChartData().then(result => { return { 2008: averageClaimByPatient(result[2008]), 2009: averageClaimByPatient(result[2009]) }` ?Basically return an object where keys' values are defined return of Promise.resolve functions

Comment: You'll have to use `Promise.all` to wait for both Promises to resolve before returning the object. https://jsfiddle.net/a3q1eowr/

Comment: Incredible, I've been learning on and off for a few years now and this async stuff gets me every single time. Need a way to commit these concepts to memory so that I can stop the long setbacks of reading through docs and examples and failing to apply them to my use case.

Comment: Ugh, I make a few steps forward and async starts kicking my ass again. So, I export a function with the promise chain like above starting with `produceChartData()` and eventually returning the `Promise.all` results. Calling it like `mod.func().then(result => console.log(result)` in a different file produces `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Why Is that so?

Comment: Sounds like `mod.func`, whatever it is, isn't returning a `Promise` (or anything at all)? Make sure to use `return`, I guess?

Comment: I am returning, here is what I basically have https://gist.github.com/syivanes/015d869111e435207493fe82b118c446

Comment: You're not returning the Promise chain. Change to `return produceChartData()...`

Answer (score 2):

For promises to work you need a "root of asynchrony", which is a callback. As your function `produceChartData` does not accept a callback nor returns a promise, it cannot be used. But its quite easy to add:

```
 const produceChartData = () => new Promise(resolve => { // return a promise and produce a callback
   inputStream
    .pipe(CsvReadableStream())
    .on('data', function (row) {
      if ((20080101 <= row[3]) && (row[3] <= 20081231)) {
        yearTotal2008 += parseFloat(row[6])
        yearPatientTally(year2008TallyByPatient, row[0],  parseFloat(row[6]))
     }
  })
  .on('end', function (data) {
     console.log('end of the read')
     console.log('year total claims: ' + yearTotal2008)
     console.log('average claims by patient: ' + averageClaimByPatient(year2008TallyByPatient))
     resolve({ yearTotal2008, year2008TallyByPatient }); // call back
  })
});
```

Which can be used as:

```
 produceChartData().then(({ yearTotal2008 }) => {
   console.log(yearTotal2008);
 });
```

Comment: `"root of asynchronity"` I like this phrase, except asynchronity isn't a word, but asynchrony is :p

Comment: @jaromanda ouch, I really thought that asynchronity would exist, and so [do others](https://www.google.es/search?q=asynchronity&oq=asynchronity&aqs=chrome..69i57.2023j0j7&client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), at least I'm not the only one getting it wrong ... :)

Comment: I wasn't criticising ... I really do like that term